# "X Error" BadAlloc GLX BadContext on IntelSandyBridge (Intel HD Graphics 3000)

Tags: xorg, bad-alloc, glx, backport, mesa

I'm running a `debian stable` ThinkPad X1 (1294-3QG) with exactly three packages from `squeeze-backports` needed for the GraphicsModi:

```
initramfs-tools 0.99~bpo60+1
linux-base 3.4~bpo60+1
linux-image-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 3.2.9-1~bpo60
```

While running that kernel, starting for example `paraview` results in those errors:

```
Unrecognized deviceID 126
X Error: BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation) 11
  Extension:    154 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 3 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x3200273
X Error: GLXBadContext 169
  Extension:    154 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x32002b0
paraview: ../../src/xcb_io.c:183: process_responses: Zusicherung Â»!(req && current_request && !(((long) (req->sequence) - (long) (current_request)) <= 0))Â« nicht erfÃ¼llt.
```

Somewhere on the net, I found the hint to offer the memory settings in the `xorg.conf`, but that did not solve my problem.
Starting within the current stable kernel works fine.

Running `glxgears`results similar:

```
Unrecognized deviceID 126
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

I further tried, to solve the problem by updating `xserver-xorg-video-intel` (and all dependencies `libdrm-intel1 libxfont1, xserver-common, xserver-xorg, xserver-xorg-core, xserver-xorg-input-evdev, xserver-xorg-video-fbdev` and `xserver-xorg-video-vesa`) to backports, but that was not prosperous.

Additional, I found the entry

```
[drm] MTRR allocation failed.  Graphics performance may suffer.
```

in the output of `dmesg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it now on my own by updating some `mesa` concerning packages. I'm running debian stable with those following packages from backports:

> initramfs-tools, libdrm-intel1, libgl1-mesa-dev, libgl1-mesa-dri,
>   libgl1-mesa-glx, linux-base, linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.1-all-amd64,
>   linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.1-amd64, linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.1-common,
>   linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.1-common-rt,
>   linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.1-rt-amd64,
>   linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-all-amd64,
>   linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64, linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-common,
>   linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-common-rt,
>   linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-rt-amd64, linux-image-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64,
>   linux-kbuild-3.2, mesa-common-dev

Hoping this info will help other, too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on self-made server station with Intel i7 2700k (which has Intel HD 3000) running Debian Stable 6.0.4 (squeeze) x64. Basically I knew that this platform has loads of problems with unix systems (as always intel GPU does), but it purpose is server, so on-board graphic is fair enough for that. Anyways I wanted someday to run just a move (on TV connected via HDMI*/VGA), so I installed gnome-core with gdm3 to run manually.

With kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64 everything was excellent, besides few things, which forced me to upgrade kernel:

- SSD support (added & improved from linux-image-2.6.33)
- HDMI - no devices was recognized, couldn't add & change resolution (cvt xrandr).

So I added squeeze-backports to sources.list and upgraded only kernel (same what you did).

After that HDMI connection works great, but I noticed slow refresh rate - tearing during loading gdm3 login screen and after. I checked dmesg and kernel messages for some infos

- cat dmesg | grep failed && cat dmesg | grep drm && cat /var/log/messages | grep failed && cat /var/log/messages | grep drm - found same. Than I run glxgears and found same error.

I was digging net for few days after some solutions and ideas.
Found many useless things about allocating RAM (enable_mtrr_cleanup) etc.
Basically for my hardly ever cinematic needs it wasn't tragedy, but I like when everything is perfect, so I still was working around to fix it.

And at last! Got it solved! Problem was not with the RAM or new kernel itself.

I have to mention here, that I compiled Debian kernel myself - 3.2 based on settings from previous install.

- I removed also all unneeded libs for my architecture (i.e. libdrm for nvidia radeon and others - even VESA!!!)

I added just for a moment wheezy (testing) repositories, upgraded and installed new packages with dependences as root (only this ones):

- echo deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list
- apt-get update
- apt-get install --reinstall -t testing libdrm2 libdrm-intel1 xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri mesa-utils
- dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

That fixed all problems with rendering and allocation on Intel GPU :)

Think it should works for you and everyone with Intel GPU-s. Don't forget to remove wheeze (testing) from sources.list when you are done.

Regards, T_Send.

Comment: Thanks T_Send for your lines! Just returned from vacation I tried - but that did not work. I tried around further with mesa and so so - and solved for me: I'll edit the question.